# What is the configuration property of read-body in Spring Cloud Gateway used for and how to use it

Tags: java, spring, yaml, spring-cloud, gateway

Today, I learned how to implement the gateway for my current project, using the Spring Cloud Gateway

Found a configuration in the configuration file that is:

```yaml
spring:
 cloud:
    gateway:
      predicate:
        read-body:
          enabled: true
```

After reviewing Spring's official website document, I couldn't find a very useful description, only saw one sentence:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGRtK.png)
At first, I thought it was a use of ReadBodyPredicteFactory, but this PredicteFactory already has a way of using it:

```yaml
predicates:
   - Path=/**
   - name: ReadBodyPredicateFactory
```

When writing my own demo and trying to use read-body, there will also be a prompt message:
Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.cloud.gateway.predicate.read-body.enabled'

So what exactly is read-body used for

I would like to know how to use this configuration property